# Palindrome Test Also Needs to Return False

Tags: javascript, palindrome

```
function palindrome(str) {
    str.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~   ()]/g,"").toLowerCase().split().reverse().join();
    return true;
}
palindrome("eye");
```

Comment: Well, do you understand what your code does, and what it should do? Of course it only returns `true`, that's what you told it to do. When should it return `true` and when should it return `false`? Once you can answer yourself those questions, at least in words if not in code, the solution should be easier.

Comment: If the string backwards is not a palindrome, then false. So I should insert an if statement.

Comment: Not necessarily an `if` statement - you need a comparison, but comparison directly returns `true` or `false`. It is redundant to write `if (condition) then return true; else return false;` when you can just `return condition;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at your code, you are returning `true` no matter what. You need to test if the string is equal to the reversed string.

```
function palindrome (str) {
    var string = (str+'').replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~\ ()]/g,"").replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
    return string === (string.split('').reverse().join(''));
}
```

---

### Broken Down

- First, we create a private variable `_str`. We make it a string using `+''`. Then I put your replace code to replace those characters.
- Now, we have a conditional statement. This is seeing if `_str` made is the same as it reversed. `.split('').reverse().join('')` is to reverse the string. `return` will return wether this is true or not

---

## Tests:

> `isPalendrome(151);`     ➥ true
>
> `isPalendrome('eye');` ➥ true
>
> `isPalendrome(2552);`   ➥ true
>
> `isPalendrome(12);`       ➥ false
>
> `isPalendrome('foo');` ➥ false

Comment: Got it, an if statement is not always needed for a comparison. thanks

Comment: Still receiving a few error messages. Also, I changed the name of the function to palindrome for it is expected to be named that.

Comment: undefined

assert.deepEqual(palindrome("never odd or even"), true);AssertionError:expected false to deeply equal true
assert.deepEqual(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"), true);AssertionError:expected false to deeply equal true
assert.deepEqual(palindrome("race car"), true);AssertionError:expected false to deeply equal true

Comment: that was it. I forgot all out the lowercase function being needed.